# Multiple select statement in hive

Tags: hive

toi am fairly new to hive.
I have a table called stats as shown below

```
from_date  |  to_date   |   customer_name |  callcount
-------------------------------------------------------
2016_01_01 | 2016_01_02 |  ABC            | 25  
2016_01_02 | 2016_01_03 |  ABC            | 53  
2016_01_03 | 2016_01_04 |  ABC            | 44  
2016_01_04 | 2016_01_05 |  ABC            | 55
```

I want to build a hive query will accept:
a) current time range (from and to time)
b) previous time range (from and to time)
c) customer name

For e.g.: the inputs will be:
current time range can be from time(2016_01_03) and to time(2016_01_05)
current time range can be from time(2016_01_01) and to time(2016_01_02) 
customer name can be ABC

And the result i want to display is:
current_call_count(sum of call counts for current time range), previous_call_count(sum of call counts for previous time range)
and difference between current_call_count & previous_call_count

like this:

```
customer | current_call_count | previous_call_count | Diff
---------------------------------------------------------
ABC      | 99                 | 25                  | 74
```

The query which i built was:

```
select * from 
(
select sum(callCount) as current_count from stats 
where customer_name='ABC' and from_date>='2016-04-03' and to_date<='2016-04-05'
UNION ALL
select sum(callCount) as current_count from stats 
where customer_name='ABC' and from_date>='2016-04-01' and to_date<='2016-04-02'
  ) FINAL
```

I am not able to get the calculation and also not able to display result as columns. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    sum(case when from_date >= '2016_01_04' and to_date <= '2016_01_05' then callcount else 0 end)
    as current_call_count,
    sum(case when from_date >= '2016_01_02' and to_date <= '2016_01_03' then callcount else 0 end)
    as previous_call_count,
    sum(case when from_date >= '2016_01_04' and to_date <= '2016_01_05' then callcount else 0 end)
    - sum(case when from_date >= '2016_01_02' and to_date <= '2016_01_03' then callcount else 0 end)
    as difference
from stats
where customer_name = 'ABC'
```

Note that your example data uses `_` instead of `-` (which is used in your query) as a date separator.